# Couldn't import Google Map API

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps

Here' my error message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'map'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
      > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1:.
        Required by:
            project :
```

And here's my android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1")
    }
     
    
}
```

At first, I did't change anything about the code, and the emulator showed a error "API key not found", but I thought my AndroidManifest.xml file doesn't have question.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="MY-API-KEY"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.

It must be `classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1"` instead of `classpath("com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1"`.

Notice the symbol after `gms`.